# dynamically finding value from key string in nested hash

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I have a user inputed string called `x_value` whose value contains something like `ticker|high`. Whenever there is a `|`, that indicates that the latter is a child of the former. The purpose of the method is to return a specific value within a hash.

```
sections = []
object.x_value.split('|').each do |part|
  sections << part.to_sym
end
```

I then want to drill down the data hash and retrieve the value of the last key.

```
data = {"ticker":{"high":529.5,"low":465,"avg":497.25,"vol":7520812.018}}
```

In this example

`data[sections[0]][sections[1]]` returns the expected `529.5` value. However, the user may have different hashes and different levels deep of nested key/values. How can I write this?

I have tried `data[sections]`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use recursion:

```
def getit(hash, x_value)
  recurse(hash, x_value.split('|'))
end

def recurse(hash, keys)
  k = keys.shift
  keys.empty? ? hash[k] : recurse(hash[k], keys)
end

data = {"ticker" => {"high" => 529.5, "low" => 465}}
getit(data, "ticker|high")            #=> 529.5
getit(data, "ticker")                 #=> {"high"=>529.5, "low"=>465}

data = {"more_ticker" => {"ticker" => {"high" => 529.5, "low" => 465}}}
getit(data, "more_ticker|ticker|low") #=> 465
getit(data, "more_ticker|ticker|avg") #=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

```
data = {"ticker" => {"high" => 529.5, "low" => 465,"avg" => 497.25,"vol" => 7520812.018}}
"ticker|high".split('|').reduce(data) { |dat,val| dat[val] } #=> 592.5
```

more example:

```
data = {"more_ticker" => {"ticker" => {"high" => 529.5, "low" => 465,"avg" => 497.25,"vol" => 7520812.018}}}
"more_ticker|ticker|avg".split('|').reduce(data) { |dat,val| dat[val] } 
#=> 497.25
```

Comment: Interesting, unconventional use of `reduce`, bjhaid.  I must tuck that away.